# Using Doctrine DBAL to create views and stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo

We are using Doctrine in a Symfony2 application. In order to help with some database interactions, we have defined some views and stored procedures. These are stored in a specific directory of our project source and then put under version control so everyone in the team can have access to them. Each view or stored procedure has its own .sql file containing the query that will create the view / stored procedure, including a "drop if already exists" line.

We have written a console command to go through the directory that holds the .sql files and then issues the query to the database via a PDO object created from the Doctrine dbal connection.

Examination of the MySQL query log reveals that each "CREATE VIEW" and "CREATE PROCEDURE" command has been executed, and the PDO connection is not giving any errors. But, when we examine the database after the command have run, not all the expected items exist. Here is the strange bit... at the moment, we have commands to create 3 views and 1 stored procedure. When we run the command for the first time, 2 of the views are created. Then, we run it again, and the third view is created. The stored procedure is never created, no matter how many times we run the command.

So, can anyone offer any help as to why this could be happening. The database user has the necessary privileges and the query log suggests everything is fine.

Here is the execute method of the console command;

```
/**
* execute command
*
* @param InputInterface  $input
* @param OutputInterface $output
*/
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $path = $input->getArgument('path');

    $this->setAbsolutePath($path);

    if (!$this->doesPathExist()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException($this->absolutePath.' does not exist, or is not a directory');
    }

    $files = $this->getFiles();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $bits = explode('.', $file);
        if (count($bits)>1) {
            $extension = end($bits);
            if (strtolower($extension) === 'sql' ) {

                if ($this->runScript($file)) {
                    $output->writeln($file.' ran successfully!');
                } else {
                    $output->writeln($file. ' errored!');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $output->writeln('Done');
}
```

which calls this method 'runScript'...

```
/**
* run script
* executes the sql commands in the provided file
* returns true if the script executed, false otherwise
*
* @param string $filename
*
* @return boolean
*/
private function runScript($filename)
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $host = $connection->getHost();
    $username = $connection->getUsername();
    $password = $connection->getPassword();
    $database = $connection->getDatabase();
    $pdoConn = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);

    $result = false;

    if ($pdoConn) {
        $result = false;
        $script = file_get_contents($this->absolutePath.'/'.$filename);
        $stmt = $pdoConn->prepare($script);
        try {
            $result = $stmt->execute();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $result = false;
        }
        unset($stmt);
    }
    unset($pdoConn);

    return $result;
}
```

AS you can see, we've been experimenting with creating a completely new PDO database connection to issue the commands. When the command is run, it lists the four .sql files and says they all run successfully.

If we execute the .sql files directory using MySQL on the command line, using the same user that Symfony uses to connect to the database, all the views and procedures are created correctly, so we're sure there are no errors in the .sql files.

We're stumped!

Comment: Figured out why one view was not created - it relied on the other views being there, and its creation script was being run first.

Comment: Still puzzled as to why PDO did not give an error when trying to create a view that depends on a non-existent view, however.

Comment: Since you're using Doctrine, can you explain why you are using PDO to handle the actual execution of the stored procedures? It seems like a good use case for `createNativeQuery`.

Comment: Did you try using directly DBAL connection ? "MySQL query log" are replication binlogs or doctrine logs ?

Comment: We've tried using DBAL directly and got the same results.

Comment: The "MySQL query log" is the General Query Log obtained by setting general_log = 'ON' in MySQL.

Comment: I will try using a NativeQuery

Answer (score 3):

The problem was using DELIMITER $$ in the definition of the stored procedure. The definition was originally written using the MySQL command line, so it needed to differentiate between real semi-colons that denote the end of a command, and the ones in the stored procedure.So, the Delimiter was changed.

This is not needed when creating the stored procedure via the DBAL / PDO connection.

So, in short, the solution was to stick with using semi-colons as delimiters throughout the .sql script that creates the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks, saved me time!